# Install ShareLatex on a RaspberryPi / no matching manifest for linux/arm in the manifest list entries

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker-compose

I try to install ShareLatex like this:

https://www.ioblogger.de/2017/03/sharelatex-docker-image-einrichtung-unter-debian-8-inkl-aller-texlive-pakete-und-systemd/

But after this command:

docker-compose up

I'll get this error:

$ docker-compose up
Pulling mongo (mongo:latest)...
latest: Pulling from library/mongo
ERROR: no matching manifest for linux/arm in the manifest list entries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out: ShareLaTex do not run on ARM!